# Delphi datetimepicker component set min and max time

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

Does anybody know if there is a way in Delphi to set a max time and min time value for a Datetimepicker component when the component `kind` property is set to `dtkTime`?

Comment: Nope, I don't think that this control offers such functionality

Comment: No, it does not. It supports min/max *dates*, but not min/max *times*. You will have to use the `OnChange` and `OnUserInput` events to tweak entered times as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VCL class `TDateTimePicker` seems to purposely prevent setting the time range values. However, the underlying common control supports it, at least in Windows 7 where I've tried the following code with success:

```
uses
  System.DateUtils,
  Winapi.CommCtrl,
  Vcl.ComCtrls;

procedure SetTimeRange(CommonCalendar: TCommonCalendar; MinTime, MaxTime: TTime);
var
  STA: TSystemTimeRangeArray;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(TimeOf(MinTime), STA[0]);
  DateTimeToSystemTime(TimeOf(MaxTime), STA[1]);
  Win32Check(DateTime_SetRange(CommonCalendar.Handle, GDTR_MIN or GDTR_MAX, @STA));
end;
```

Example usage:

```
  SetTimeRange(DateTimePicker1, EncodeTime(18, 0, 0, 0), EncodeTime(19, 0, 0, 0));
```